# The number of points on given line which are at some distance from a fixed given point.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

**Question**

The number of points on the line $3x+4y=5$, which are at a distance $$(sec(\theta))^2 + 2 (cosec(\theta))^2$$, where $\theta$ ∈ $R$ , from the point (1,3) is___ .

*My attempt*

$$d= \frac{|3(1)+4(3)-5|}{5}$$
$$(sec(\theta))^2 + 2 (cosec(\theta))^2=|2|$$
$$(sec(\theta))^2 + 2 (cosec(\theta))^2=2$$
$$ 1+ (tan(\theta))^2 + 2+ 2(cot(\theta))^2=2$$
$$(tan(\theta))^2 + 2(cot(\theta))^2=-1$$

**My doubt**

It comes to be the sum of squares of two terms be negative. How is this ever possible? Is the question wrong or my 
thought process?

Answer (score 1):

If we call the point $P$, and the line $l$, you used the distance from a $P$ to $l$. This formula gives you the smallest $d$ such that $d$ is the distance from $p$ to $L_0$, where $L_0$ is a point on $l$. That is, the distance from a point to a line is defined as the distance from the point to the closest point on the line.

The question asks you to find how many points $L_n$ there are on $l$ that are the given distance from $P$. So you want the distance from $L_n$ to $P$, not $L_0$ to $P$.  The latter is a start, however. You know that the distance to the closest point is $2$. And you know that $(\sec(\theta))^2 + 2 (\csc(\theta))^2$ is at least $3$. Try drawing a graph. How do you draw the set of point of distance $3$ from $p$? How many of those points are on $l$? What if you want a distance greater than $3$?

Comment: So, it doesn't ask about the smallest,  but, the distance value obtain by the trigonometric expression satisfied by those some point on the given line to (1,3).